# How to tip in Israel?

Tags: local-customs, israel, tipping, etiquette

What's the proper etiquette for tipping in taxis, restaurants, cafes, hairdressers, etc.? See [equivalent question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8824/how-to-tip-in-the-united-states?rq=1) for the US.

I've heard many different opinions online and during my travels, so I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Tipping in Israel

First things first: [tipping is discretionary](http://igoogledisrael.com/2011/12/tipping-in-israel-when-and-how-much/). You have no obligation to tip anyone, although showing appreciation for good service is often a good idea.

[Who to Tip has a great webpage on Israel](http://www.whototip.net/tipping-in-israel), which seems to summarise the general consensus found on the internet. In general, cash tips are preferred. I paraphrase below the main tipping tips I found while scouring the web.

#### Restaurans / Bars / Cafes / Food Delivery

The tip usually oscillates between 10% and 15%. The latter being a generous tip. The average seems to be 12%. Leave cash tips, since [paying tips via card seems to be uncommon/hard](http://howtobeisraeli.blogspot.fr/2010/05/how-to-tip-like-israeli.html). Leaving 5-10% tip to your food delivery man is common practice.

#### Hotels

Give 5 NIS per bag to your bellman, 5-10 NIS per day to the maids. Check if tip is included in room service, if not 5-10% is a good amount.

#### Tour Guides

Give 15% to your tour guide, if they work for a private company. Self-employed guides will include the tip in the total cost of the tour. Don't forget to tip the driver some 120-150 NIS.

#### Taxi Drivers

Tipping taxi drivers isn't required. You can always round up the fare to the nearest integer value, if you feel like it.

#### Spas

Tipping attendants isn't required. Tipping therapists isn't mandatory but some people do it. [Possible amounts could be](http://www.israel-travel-tips.com/en/167/General%20Info/FAQs/Israel%20tipping%20guidelines%20-%20how%20to%20tip%20in%20Israel):

> #### Hairdressing and spa tips
>
> - Hairdresser / Stylist – 20 NIS
> - Shampooer – 10 NIS
> - Nails – 10 NIS
> - Masseuse – 20 NIS
> - Spa Attendant – no need to tip